# Работа с ComboBox в WF

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброе время суток. Имеется ComboBox с выпадающими элементами. Каким образом я могу отключить какой-либо элемент? (то есть , чтобы он показывался в списке, а выбрать его было нельзя, удалять элемент не нужно).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В свойствах ComboBox установите DrawMode к OwnerDrawFixed, после эти два события:

```
Font  myFont = new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Regular);

private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{        
    if (e.Index == 1)//Отключение элемента на основе индекса
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), myFont, Brushes.LightGray, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), myFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
} 

 void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //если выбранный индекс=1 нельзя выбирать
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```